# Use pickerview information in other view?

Tags: view, picker, tabbed

I have a tabbed application. I have 4 tabs and in the first 2 tabs there are pickerviews. How can I use the information that im giving in the first and second picker view, in the third tab ?  for example:  1 picker view : (which is your favorite animal)  Dog, cat, horse.  I choose Dog. now in the second tab (2nd picker view):  (which colour, whatever) green, blue, brown. I choose brown.

I want the first Information(Dog) to be able to be used in the third Tab. The options: green, blue and brown (example) are (whatever i choose) the same. But in the third view there should be a brown dog (as text for ex. "you choosed the brown dog"). I hope you know what i mean... 1. selection: Dog 2. brown = 3rd Tab brown dog. It's like a little data base... or how can I do this? I hope you can help me.

Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
See the code 

-(IBAction)simple_picker:(id)sender{

    pickerViewPopup = [[UIActionSheet alloc] init];
    const CGFloat toolbarHeight = 44.0f;
    Picker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, toolbarHeight, 0, 0)];
    Picker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    Picker.dataSource = self;
    Picker.delegate = self;
    //........
    UIToolbar *pickerToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, toolbarHeight)];
    pickerToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
    [pickerToolbar sizeToFit];
    NSMutableArray *barItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    UIBarButtonItem *cancel= [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(Cancel_picker:)];
    [barItems addObject:cancel];
    UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];
    [barItems addObject:flexSpace];
    //....
    UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(doneButtonPressed2:)];
    [barItems addObject:doneBtn];
    [pickerToolbar setItems:barItems animated:YES];
    [pickerViewPopup addSubview:pickerToolbar];

    lbl2.text=[picArray objectAtIndex:0];

    [pickerViewPopup addSubview:Picker];
    [pickerViewPopup showInView:self.view.superview];
    [pickerViewPopup setBounds:CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width, 464)];

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView;
{
    return 1;
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
            lbl2.text= [picArray objectAtIndex:row];


}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component;
{

    return [picArray count];

}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component;
{

return [picArray objectAtIndex:row];


}


-(void)btncancelPressed2:(id)sender{
    [pickerViewPopup dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:1 animated:YES];
}

-(void)Cancel_picker:(id)sender{
    [pickerViewPopup dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:1 animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer!